# iPhone SDK backwards Building?

Tags: iphone

With the imminent release of iPhone_OS_4 is there a way I can install that version and still build for the current 3.2 release? Or do I need to install OS_4 as a separate install and do all my development on the 3.2 release?

cheers gary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All iPhone SDK includes previous versions of SDKs.

That applies to 4.0 SDK too (which includes 3.0 — 4.0.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a drop-down menu in the top-left corner of Xcode that lets you choose what version of the SDK to build with and whether to run on a simulator or on a device.

Just select the version you want and it does the rest.

Comment: Ah I did see that, but as I only have 1 version installed I did not realise it would let you select others.